# Search the list of text in another sheet and copy all match to different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA Macros. So wanted a help. I have a list of text in a column. I want to find all match in a excel sheet and copy all to another sheet.

Comment: Edit your question with your code and explains what problem do you have.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.